# how to use pythontex in winedt

Tags: miktex, winedt, pythontex

is there a shortcut within WinEdt to use the pythontex command?

For the pythontex command, I know that you have to use the command prompt and then go to the path where the pythontex file is stored.  In my example it is at:
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex

Then you have to type in the path to the file that you need to compile for pythontex.  I will then have to type:
pythontex C:\Users\superman\Desktop\test\example

Can WinEdt be customized to carry out these steps in a more efficient manner, for example by creating a button??

OK, I followed some steps and copied all the text from the active toolbar.ini file (in my case all the verbage in Toolbar2d.ini) and copied it to Private.ini under the 
\  My custom Tex toolbar:
[TOOLBAR*]

I added:

```
  BUTTON="|"   
  BUTTON="PyTeX"
  BUTTON="|"
```

to the bottom of the file.

I would like to know what commands to input in the MainMenu.ini file.  I did a copy/past and have this so far appened to the end of the MainMenu.ini file:

```
ITEM="PyTeX"
CAPTION="&PyTeX"
IMAGE="Python"
MACRO="Exe('%b\Exec\TeX\dvi2ps.edt');" % need to get the command for the pythontex execution
SHORTCUT="24644::Shift+Ctrl+Y"
REQ_FILTER="%P\%N.dvi" % need to change for pythontex to run
ITEM="-"
```

Can you help me edit these commands to run the pythontex?

Comment: Yes you can create such buttons. See the documentation of the option interface.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I am able to get the button to show up on the toolbar but it is greyed out?  Can you assist me in getting the correct command for the pythontex to run (i.e. the correct command) and have the button not show up as greyed out?

Comment: I would at first try to use Run and not Exe, e.g. `MACRO="Run('pythontex  %n%t')"` (check the parameters of Run in the macro manual).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update (2016-04-10)

A new add-on [PythonTeX](http://www.winedt.org/config/menus/PythonTeX.html) is available for WinEdt, so, if you want, revert the changes you've made in MainMenu.ini and install this package.

Be sure to have PythonTeX installed correctly, i.e. run the script `python­tex_in­stall.bat` bundled with PythonTeX.

---

### Original answer

I don't have neither Python nor PythonTeX installed, so I couldn't try it, but the following should work.

In your local copy of MainMenu.ini, just before the line

```
  ITEM="ConTeXt"
```

add the following lines

```
  ITEM="PyTeX"
    CAPTION="PyTeX"
    IMAGE="Python"
    SAVE_INPUT=1
    MACRO=`WinExe('','"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex.exe" "%N%T"','%P','',100,0,'','','',0);`
    SHORTCUT="24665::Shift+Ctrl+Y"
    REQ_FILTER=:"%!M=TeX"|"%!M=TeX:STY"|"%!M=TeX:AUX"
  ITEM="-"
```

Adjust the command line inside `MACRO` to your settings.

Then press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+F9</kbd> to reload the file.

If `pythontex` in your command line is not an executable, but a python script, as I suspect, replace the `MACRO` line with the following:

```
    MACRO=`WinExe('','cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex" "%N%T""','%P','',100,0,'','','',0);`
```

---

### EDIT

If you're redirecting your auxiliary files to another folder, you will have the need to move the `.pytxcode` file to your main directory.

In this case, substitute the `MACRO` line with the following:

```
    MACRO=`IfStr("%O","%P","<>",!|IfFileExists('%O\%N.pytxcode',!'CopyFile("%O\%N.pytxcode","%P\%N.pytxcode",1);DeleteFile("%O\%N.pytxcode");');|);`+
          `WinExe('','cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex" "%N%T""','%P','',100,0,'','','',0);`+
          `IfStr("%O","%P","<>",!|IfFileExists('%P\%N.pytxcode',!'CopyFile("%P\%N.pytxcode","%O\%N.pytxcode",1);DeleteFile("%P\%N.pytxcode");');|);`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I think that I am much closer after your input.  I put your commands in however the CMD window pops up and just ask to press any key. It does not seem to run pythontex. If I have to run python tex manually on my tex file named Cplusplus.tex, this is my full dos command "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex F:\Desktop\techpapers\Cplusplus", where the tex file is located at F:\Desktop\techpapers\Cplusplus. I did modify your MACRO to...'"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex" "%N%T"','%P'...

Comment: @Joe Surely it didn't work because `pythontex` in your command line is `pythontex.py` and not `pythontex.exe`. See if the edited code works.

Comment: much closer...you are correct with your comment that it is a pyton script that needs to be run.  When I try your updated command, the CMD says 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I got your command to work by slightly  modifying your code to: MACRO=`WinExe('','cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\pythontex\pythontex" "%N%T""','%P','',100,0,'','','',111);`.  I had to put in the extra ".  However, the command promt window remains open after executing the command as it asks to "press any key to continue..."  Is there an extra tweak to the command that will close the command window down when it is done?

Comment: @joe substitute the last `111` with `0`

Comment: I have a slight modification request.  My tex files are in a subfolder called 'Chapters' and all the aux files are created in another folder called TeXAux after running LaTeX.  With this folder system, I get the error in the CMD window saying that `Code file xxxx.pytxcode does not exist.`.  Only when I move the pytxcode from the TeXAux folder (where it was originally created) to the main folder, only then pythontex runs successfully.  Do I have to move the pytxcode file every time to the main folder, or can the MACRO be modified to accommodate this folder structure?

Comment: @Joe See the edit.

Comment: You are a rock star! Works Perfectly!